# Woff2 Font-Family warning message about MaxZones

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, woff2

I am trying to use a Woff2 font called "Atkinson Hyperlegible". The font can be found here: https://brailleinstitute.org/freefont

It's a very popular font. But when I import it, and I use Firefox, I see this error in my console.

```
downloadable font: maxp: Bad maxZones: 0 (font-family: "Atkinson Hyperlegible" style:normal weight:600 stretch:100 src index:0) source: http://127.0.0.1:3000/fonts/Atkinson-Hyperlegible-Bold-102a.woff2
```

The font works, but I am getting this warning for each time I used the font on my site. How can I resolve it?

Here is how I import it:

```
/* Atkinson Hyperlegible - Regular */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atkinson Hyperlegible';
    src: url('/fonts/Atkinson-Hyperlegible-Regular-102a.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Atkinson Hyperlegible - Italic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atkinson Hyperlegible';
    src: url('/fonts/Atkinson-Hyperlegible-Italic-102a.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Atkinson Hyperlegible - Bold */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atkinson Hyperlegible';
    src: url('/fonts/Atkinson-Hyperlegible-Bold-102a.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Atkinson Hyperlegible - Bold Italic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Atkinson Hyperlegible';
    src: url('/fonts/Atkinson-Hyperlegible-BoldItalic-102a.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Then I use it like so:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Atkinson Hyperlegible';
}
```

I am only getting this error message in Firefox. I have tried renaming the font to just "atkinson" but that did not work either...

Comment: This appears to be a minor compiling error. If you convert the the ttf to woff2 manually via [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) the message disapears in FF.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenType font format defines a ["maximum profile" table (tag: 'maxp')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/maxp) that is meant to provide info that a rasterizer can use for allocating memory resources when loading a font. One of the data fields in that table is maxZones, which is used to provide certain info about glyph hinting instructions used in the font.

The error indicates that the maxZones value in the font is 0, but that's not a valid value: the value must be either 1 or 2.

You can probably disregard that error: if the app does use hinting, then the rasterizer will probably figure out what the value should have been or allocate resources for the worst-case scenario.

You could provide feedback to the agency distributing the font that is has that error. Perhaps they'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to let you know I ran in this issue with the same font in Firefox, and I found a very simple fix in this GH-issue: https://github.com/ecomfe/fontmin/issues/83#issuecomment-1143771799

As stated in that issue you might just have to remove the space between property name and value like that:

`font-family:'Atkinson Hyperlegible';`

instead of

`font-family: 'Atkinson Hyperlegible';`.

It solved the problem on my side.

More detail can be found there:

- https://github.com/mclemente/fvtt-module-polyglot/issues/64
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80474/how-can-i-solve-font-downloadable-error-downloadable-font-os-2-bad-linegap

Hope it'll help!